# Problem with "outDir" in tsconfig.json - VS Code red mark

Tags: angular

Question:
I am encountering an issue with the TypeScript configuration in my tsconfig.json file. In Visual Studio Code, I see a red mark on the "outDir" option. Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

I don't have the "dist/out-tsc" directory, and the red mark persists. I've tried creating the directory manually, but the issue remains. What could be causing this problem, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: please hover over the red mark and show the error message, also if its not blocking your development, ignore it!

Comment: Cannot find the common subdirectory path for the input files.ts
Specify an output folder for all emitted files.

See more: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outDir

Answer (score 0):

After checking the internet, I found this [github issue](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript/issues/193) very similar to your problem, maybe upgrade `node` to a higher version, maybe it will fix your issue!